VS Code tracking changes without connecting to remote repository
I once connected to a repository on github, and since then, when I start another project in another folder, just by having a .gitignore (like creating a React app) VS Code is already tracking the changes and suggesting commits, even without being connected to a repository on github.
I have no idea why this happens, I don't have much knowledge of git yet.

What output does running git remote -v from the command line in the folder of such a project produce?

@hlovdal fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

what do you see in the source control view? what is the output of running ls -a in your workspace folder?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
